# Beside "לא תבשל", what phrases appear several times in the Torah and interpreted as different Halachot?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, halacha-theory

Famously, "לא תבשל" appears three times in the Torah in different verses:

> "רֵאשִׁ֗ית בִּכּוּרֵי֙ אַדְמָ֣תְךָ֔ תָּבִ֕יא בֵּ֖ית ה"א לֹֽא־תְבַשֵּׁ֥ל גְּדִ֖י בַּחֲלֵ֥ב אִמֹּֽו׃" שמות כג יט
> "רֵאשִׁ֗ית בִּכּוּרֵי֙ אַדְמָ֣תְךָ֔ תָּבִ֕יא בֵּ֖ית ה"א לֹא־תְבַשֵּׁ֥ל גְּדִ֖י בַּחֲלֵ֥ב אִמֹּֽו׃" שמות לד כו
> "לֹ֣א תֹאכְל֣וּ כׇל־נְ֠בֵלָה לַגֵּ֨ר אֲשֶׁר־בִּשְׁעָרֶ֜יךָ תִּתְּנֶ֣נָּה וַאֲכָלָ֗הּ אֹ֤ו מָכֹר֙ לְנׇכְרִ֔י כִּ֣י עַ֤ם קָדֹושׁ֙ אַתָּ֔ה לַה"א לֹֽא־תְבַשֵּׁ֥ל גְּדִ֖י בַּחֲלֵ֥ב אִמֹּֽו׃" דברים יד כא

and three different Halachot are learned from this fact:

> "בּג׳ מְקוֹמוֹת כָּתוּב לֹֽא־תְבַשֵּׁ֥ל גְּדִ֖י. לַאֲכִילָה וְלַהֲנָייָה וּלְבִישּׁוּל." ([Jerusalem_Talmud_Avodah_Zarah.5.12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Avodah_Zarah.5.12.8?vhe=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_edition_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

As we can see "רֵאשִׁ֗ית בִּכּוּרֵי֙ אַדְמָ֣תְךָ֔ תָּבִ֕יא בֵּ֖ית ה"א" also appear multiple times.

Are there other similar passages that are interpreted Halachicly
("Y appears X times to teach X different Halachot")?

*PS I don't include single words, for example, the word "Succah" to learn the number of walls.*

Comment: Is this not just an example of the general principle of "ribuy", in a particular case where the ribuyim are the same verse? By repeating it, it *augments* the law with additional restrictions. I'm just suggesting that calling them "different halachos" may be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemarah in Bava Metziah on Daf 61a-61b learns out different laws from the words לא תגנב etc. I am unsure exactly how to bring the source. Look there.

Comment: Isn't that a case of different prohibitions described differently,but overlap? So The gemara asks (eg) if you have issirim against ona'ah (financial exploitation) and Robbie (interest) why would you need to significant against actual theft? With lo sevasheil, it is a derashah based on the same clause being repeated in three places. An entirely different thing,

Comment: If you look further in the Gemara, closer to the bottom, you will see what I am referring to.